# How to run a stored procedure with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I don't know how to run a stored procedure with Entity Framework. I tried:

```
public static string GetGroupModFunc(string group_mod_id)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QLNTEntities"].ToString());
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_GROUP_PERMIT", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GID", group_mod_id);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    conn.Close();
    return "Test connection";
}
```

My connection string entity client

```
<add name="QLNTEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/DATA.ModelQLNT.csdl|res://*/DATA.ModelQLNT.ssdl|res://*/DATA.ModelQLNT.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=QLNT;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"  
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

After run it I get an error

> System.ArgumentException keyword not supported 'metadata'

Thank guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: how do I run a stored procedure and return a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779155/entity-framework-how-do-i-run-a-stored-procedure-and-return-a-value)

Comment: Dear all, I want to run store procedure using SQLcommand via Connection string , then bind data result to DataTable .

Comment: You can't. EntityFramework does this differently. You either drop the EntityFramework requirement (and fix your connection string) or you do it the EntityFramework way as described elsewhere. There are a ton of examples

Comment: Did you think so about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898344/execute-custom-sql-with-entity-framework

Comment: _"Did you think so about this stackoverflow.com/questions/10898344/"_ - well EF is an _ORM_ and mixing a _ORM model_ with _adhoc SQL-in-code_ is arguably code smell and perhaps defeats the purpose of any good ORM.  Much better to encapsulate the stored proc via the EF designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With code first, I use the following method from a repository;

```
public async Task<int> Query(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
    return await this._db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(query, parameters);
}
```

Where this._db is your datacontext.

Then call it as such;

```
string query = "exec <StoredProcName> @Param1, @Param2";
Task<int> a = this._repository.Query(query,
                    new SqlParameter("@Param1", "foo"),
                    new SqlParameter("@Param2", "bar"));
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In your edmx file, open model browser, and choose Add Function Import, EF will generate the proper code and models for your stored procedure accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When your model is generated from the database, then you can directly call the stored procedure as a method like this:

```
DbContextObject.YourStoredProcedureName(parameters)
```

Another alternative is,

```
Db.ExecuteFunction("Stored Procedure Name", "Parameter Collection");
```

Where Db is database context object.

Hope this helps..!

Answer (score -1):

Well , I found answer .

```
 public static string GetGroupModFunc(string group_mod_id)
    {
        var sconnect = ((SqlConnection)db.Database.Connection);
        sconnect.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_GROUP_PERMIT", sconnect);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GID", group_mod_id);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        sconnect.Close();
   //It's flexible , because it's return DataTable , not entity , You can use avery where 
   // ok the result bind to datatable .I'll convert them to JSON
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows);    
    }
```

You can try it , and give me some problem with it. Thank guys.